# a program for building a site

Tags: 12.04

I switched from Windows 9xp) to Ubuntu and I am overjoyed!! Really am!
Most things I did on Windows I can do (sometimes even better) in Ubuntu.
But.. I used Homesite on Windows. And I can't find a good website building program for Ubuntu.
Anyone any suggestions?

Thanx
Andries Meijer
(The Netherlands)

Comment: Hé Hollander, I use Blue Griffon. The basic version is free, you can add a number of non-free options. It is both GUI and code only.

Comment: @user277184: As you're a reputation 6 user: If one of the answers below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

**[Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/)** is a complete web authoring system that combines web file management and easy-to-use WYSIWYG web page editing.

KompoZer is designed to be extremely easy to use, making it ideal for non-technical computer users who want to create an attractive, professional-looking web site without needing to know HTML or web coding.

Download and installing:

1. [Ubuntu help for downloading (official)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallKompozer)
2. Find it in the [Ubuntu Software Center > Kompozer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kompozer/) directly.

Screenshots:

[image: Viewing your website editing]

[image: Text editing]

Answer (score 1):

If you are somewhat experienced you can use Bluefish editor. Look at it here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bluefish/

Answer (score 0):

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) is nice editor with good support for HTML.
Eclypse (in repositories) is another good editor.
And last but not least [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). These are the best one I have came acros.